# Magento white screen on Admin log in page?

Tags: php, magento, module, themes, config

I was trying to get Magento to load the core files from the adminHtml of the theme I'm using instead of the default core location and added the following code to my extension:

```
<stores>
<admin>
<!-- default admin design package and theme -->
    <design>
        <package>
            <name>fortis</name>
        </package>
        <theme>
            <default>default</default>
        </theme>
    </design>
</admin>
```

Now all I get is a white screen when I go to webshop/admin.
I can't even log in anymore. When I remove the code from my extensions config file and even if I disable the extension all I get is a white screen.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all please take a look at the Magento log ( /var/log/exception.log ).

Did you tried to clear Magento cache?

Comment: I deleted all sub directories of the /var/cache directory and it fixed the white screen. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 6):

I faced with the same problem. Actually it was even worse because it was a commercial product and a new hosting for me with really strange server configuration. So I couldn't made errors appear in any log file.

As I've found out the magento white screen means some PHP Fatal error occured. So there is a proper way to show them. Just add at the begin of your index.php

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

And you will see what is really happening with your magento.

Comment: Clearing Cache didn't solve the issue, then I tried this code. Still nothing shows only I see it white screen on /admin url