# Magento checkout page goes blank when checking out with a bundled product

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I'm having a problem checking out bundled products in Magento. When you proceed to checkout with a bundle product in the cart, the checkout page just shows a blank page. This problem doesn't appear when checking out with a simple product.

I installed a new onepage checkout extension which seemed to solve the problem. However I've been doing more testing and found if I was logged in as a customer and tried to checkout with a bundle product I would again see a blank page.

After doing some research into blank screens appearing during the checkout, I found many people saying increasing PHP memory will solve the problem, I've tried this to no affect.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question: [Magento How to debug blank white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784117/magento-how-to-debug-blank-white-screen)
There isn't an easy answer (especially if you've increased the memory limit!) But there may be somethign in there that might help you.

Answer (score -1):

Within Magento there are some logs : exception and error log plus reports.

Also there will be server level error log.

I recommend you go through this.

Blank page in PHP generally means there is some fatal error.

With error logs on those will be logged in error log file.

So start from there and post whatever you have in log related to checkout and blank screen.