# Magento flushing cache and all the site isn't working anymore

Tags: magento

I used Magento on a site to create an ecommerce site and when i was tryng to create a widget and finished it I used flushing cache button.
After i pressed that button my home page and admin page are all blank pages now...
Please help me.

Comment: If you have logging turned on, please check `MAGENTO_PATH/var/log/system.log` and `exception.log` , if not , please enable developer mode . http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/

Comment: Please, check your root folder is there any maintenance.flag file please remove that  and refresh you site.

Comment: 1) always use a dev site for testing, 2) always develop with the cache off, 3) check for site function after each code change, 4) revert last change that broke site and fix code issue. Code changes being done to a live site can be cumulative when the cache is turned on. Clear the cache and you don't know which of the changes broke everything. Basically at this point, revert out ALL the changes you made. If you are on a dev site, congratulations, it's only a debugging issue, not financial loss.

Comment: Possible duplicate of => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784117/magento-how-to-debug-blank-white-screen and => http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429