# Magento shows a blank/empty page. How do I solve this?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My Magento project not working after the cache cleared. It displays the only header.

The project was working fine but when I cleared cache from the `Cache Management` section in admin, the front-end stopped working. The only header section is visible, It showing blank page in place of Footer and content portion.

Comment: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento Store - magento.stackexchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution

It sounds like you want to enable Developer mode. Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

You may also want to enable display errors in index.php:

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The best way I have found to debug is with X-Debug in a local environment. You can also use log files to help debug in a production environment, if your unable to run X-Debug in the environment.

I've got a more detailed posting here:

http://www.molotovbliss.com/debugging-tips-and-tricks-with-magento-commerce

Consider also installing [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: me enable the `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in index.php .its show  `Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstItem() on a non-object in /home/sentoorfoundatio/public_html/onlineshop/app/code/community/Ves/Megamenu/Model/Megamenu.php on line 253`.

Comment: You should go to admin > VenusTheme > Ves Megamenu > Manage Menu Items. Then click on button “Import categories”. The problem because the megamenu don’t have any menu items.

Comment: Now revert the .htaccess and index.php changes

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code in your `index.php` file

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

Just paste it at the top. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28276042/4684797).

**Warning!**

Only use this in developement servers, don't use it on your production site, it might reveal security vulnerabilities to hackers.