# Magento getting a blank page when create a new product

Tags: magento

Today when i try to create a product from magento backend, i got a blank page. After going through some articles i increase the memory limit in htaccess file. That also did not help to solve my issue.

Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: please enable log from backend and check if you are getting any warning or error in system.log or exception.log

Comment: in your root , go to error folder and rename local.xml.sample to local.xml and check error in create product page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Follow this post. may help you to debug the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793664/magento-shows-blank-empty-page-how-do-i-solve-this/35793858#35793858

Answer (score 0):

Could you please get follow the following step.

1 get free copy of .htaccess file and place to your installation

2. clear cache in admin panel and also reindex
3. if you got in error in messages on syslog file or exception then
   post here

Good luck with your bug resolving

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System -> Configuration -> Developer and under Log Settings set Enabled to YES.
2. Create a new product to get the blank page.
3. Go to root folder site/var/log and copy stack trace from exception.log and post it here.