# Magento admin page blank after disable plugin

Tags: magento

Unable to access magento admin url, this issue I'm facing after disable Cm_RedisSession,Cybage_SignupPromo,Magebuzz_Info plugins before disable that plugin maginto admin was properly working.

Now I'm enable these all plugin but problem is same.

Comment: remove cache and try

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the cache management.

Remove var/cache folder.

If issue is still there then check my another post. [Magento shows blank/empty page. How do I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793664/magento-shows-blank-empty-page-how-do-i-solve-this/35793858#35793858)

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure but in your root folder there is file name maintenance.flag which created by magento itself whenever corrupt extension is installed or (May Other Problem) so if this file exist delete it