# Upgrading 2.2.6 to 2.3.4 - Backend Works but Frontend Page is blank

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.3

I'm using a theme from template-monster, I have successfully upgraded from 2.1.7 to 2.2.6
I used upgrading via command line.
Technology is PHP 7.1.3 on Centos 7.
I can go to back-end fine and login and everything seems to be working (backend only).

Frontend however just shows a blank page
- I tried changing permissions several ways including chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2
- I flushed, upgraded, compile, indexed, and deployed several times in different orders
- My log files shows some warnings which tbf I'm not sure it's what's causing the blank screen

Here it is

```
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.sidebarnav' element cannot be added as child to 'div.sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'brand.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.sidebarnav' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'div.sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'brand.sidebar' tries to reorder itself towards 'catalog.compare.sidebar', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'store_switcher' tries to reorder itself towards 'copyright', but their parents are different: 'footer.grid-container' and 'footer' respectively. [] []
[2020-02-08 22:34:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.switchers' tries to reorder itself towards 'sm.header.customer.menu.wrap', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper.grid-container_inner' and '' respectively. [] []
```

My biggest issue is that I don't know how to log this issue so I can debug. All I get is some broken references, is this what's causing the problem.

How can I fix the blank screen problem?

EDIT: I upgraded to PHP 7.2.27, I removed all my static files and changed the theme to blank, deployed everything once again.
I edited the Validator.php as many suggested by changing this code

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Still no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the issue. One or more of my modules was causing the problem. I disabled them with module:disable through command. I disabled all modules related to templatemonster. You could disable them 1 by 1 and keep checking.

There's a way to debug white-screen, i found out how [here]

([Magento How to debug blank white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784117/magento-how-to-debug-blank-white-screen))